# Algorithm to find singularities of a log function

Tags: optimization

I have a numerical problem in which I need to find the values $\lambda$ for which the determinant of a matrix $A_\lambda$ is zero. (The solutions $\lambda$ will give the eigenvalues of an operator...)

For that I learnt that it is better to look for the singularities of the function $\lambda \mapsto \log(|det(A_\lambda)|)$. An example of the plot of this kind of  function on $[0,10]$ is given in the following figure:

[image]

I have two questions:

1) What algorithm is best for finding such a singularity if it is unique in a certain interval $[a,b]$?

2) How should I approach the problem of finding all singularities in an interval $[a,b]$?

[I'm not sure how to choose the right tags for this question, so please feel free to add the right ones.]

---

Perhaps an answer for 1) could be the golden ratio search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search , for the case when there is a single minimum in the interval.

Still, I have no idea how to generalize this to the case where there are multiple intervals to be chosen.

Comment: What form does $A_{\lambda}$ have?  Chances are that we can suggest a much better way of approaching this problem, but you haven't provided sufficient information about how the problem arose.

Comment: @BrianBorchers The form of $A$ is $\phi_{\omega}(\|x_i-y_j\|)$ where $\phi_\omega$ is a bessel function, so $A_\lambda$ it is not sparse.

Answer (score 3):

This is an exceptionally bad algorithm to find eigenvalues, at the very least if you're just looking for the eigenvalues of a linear operator or matrix. There are many better algorithms to do what you are trying to do.

While it is true that the mathematical definition of an eigenvalue is that $A_\lambda$ is singular, i.e. that $\det A_\lambda=0$ in the finite dimensional case, this is not a practical definition to find eigenvalues in actual applications.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of better algorithms?

Comment: Are you simply trying to find the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: I'm not looking for the eigenvalues of a matrix, but of the Laplace operator on a set. You may say that it is a bad algorithm, but there are articles on the subject which say otherwise.

Comment: To find eigenvalues of operators I would look at the Lanczos and Arnoldi algorithms.

Comment: It would seem like he is solving a nonlinear matrix eigenvalue problem. How does one apply Lanczos or Arnoldi to such problems?

Comment: @VictorLiu: I am trying to implement the Method of Fundamental Solutions; it is a specific method, and the 'finding singularities' part is for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did: the idea is to find the eigenvalues in a certain interval $[a,b]$

- choose a discretization step and a corresponding discretization of the interval and then calculate the values of the function on that discretization. This discretization must be done such that there is a reasonable equilibrium between the computation time and the precision I want. Each function computation calculates the determinant of a $100\times 100$ matrix which is obtained by evaluating a Bessel function over the entries of a distance matrix.
- find the peaks among the calculated values
- around each peak make a [golden search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) in order to find *one* precise value close to the peak

(the method is inspired from the work of Alves and Antunes: http://msvlab.hre.ntou.edu.tw/cite/CMC-Alves-2005.pdf)

This is very accurate (errors of the order $10^{-6}$) and reasonably fast (for this precision) when all the eigenvalues are simple. Things get a bit messy when eigenvalues are double and worse if they are almost double. If an eigenvalue is double then looking at the kernel of $A_\lambda$ can give the multiplicity of $\lambda$.

If the eigenvalues are almost double, the kernel of $A_\lambda$ does not *see* the eigenvalue $\lambda\pm \varepsilon$, so the only way I managed to solve this is by choosing an interval $(\lambda-\delta,\lambda+\delta)$ and make an even smaller discretization in which the almost double eigenvalues will be visible.

---

Unfortunately, in my work (of optimizing eigenvalues), eigenvalues almost always tend to get double at the optimum.

If you have any suggestions on how could I improve the presented algorithm, they are more than welcome.